# How do I create a breadcrumb with the taxonomy terms used by the node?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9, breadcrumbs

I created a vocabulary for the nodes.

> [image: screenshot]

I installed the [Easy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb) module.

When a node is tagged, for example, with *Crypto* and *ICO*, the breadcrumb should be the following one.

> Accueil >> Crypto >> ICO >> Node Title

> Home >> Term >> Sub-term >> Node Title

Nodes will only have a single term or a term and a sub-term.

Currently it does not work.

> [image: screenshot]

I also installed the [Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module.

The structure of the taxonomy is therefore exactly the same as that of the main menu, but nodes aren't attached to menus.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [Menu Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) instead of Easy Breadcrumb. This way, your breadcrumb trail is based on a menu, not the URL path. Then, use it in conjunction with Taxonomy Menu.

Comment: I don't think so, because nodes don't belong to a menu, they belong to the taxonomy.